# Correct format of query in geoprocessing tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, sql, query

In the code below, I keep getting the error *An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT OBJECTID FROM LARA_CDC WHERE County IN  ['44', '50', '74', '76']]*.

I've tried several different ways of formatting the query, with no luck. The end goal is to create a new file geodatabase table from selected records of an existing one. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
new_table = "Childcare"
new_table_path = os.path.join(table_locations, new_table)
fld = "County"
query = "{0} IN ".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(table_locations, fld))
query += " ['44', '50', '74', '76']"
....
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(table_path, table_locations, new_table, query)
```

Comment: Can you try running the query against the table in the dbms? Nothing is standing out to me  as incorrect in the query, but perhaps a column name or a data type is wrong?

Comment: Fixed, see edit.

Comment: what type of database?

Comment: @recurvata Your edit makes it sound like this is solved - if so I'd recommend you revert your edit back and post the solution as an answer.  Self-answering is fine

Comment: Ok, will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Values in list are numeric, not string - removed quote marks. Also, used curved braces - () - instead of square - []. Works now.

```
new_table = "Childcare"
new_table_path = os.path.join(table_locations, new_table)
fld = "County"
query = "{0} IN ".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(table_locations, fld))
query += " (44, 50, 74, 76)"
....
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(table_path, table_locations, new_table, query)
```